# Alert not showing in the ImagePicker

Tags: swift, xcode, camera, imagepicker

I want to offer the option to use either the photo library or the camera, but my alert to select either photos or use a camera doesn't show up when I add the present actionSheet. The compiled application goes straight to photo album without giving me the option to select camera or photo library.

This is the log from my Xcode 11:

> 2020-06-15 23:05:22.931477-0400 MeMe[6298:3505455] Attempt to present
>    on  which is waiting for a delayed presention of
>    to complete 2020-06-15
>   23:05:22.931653-0400 MeMe[6298:3505455] Attempt to present
>    on 
>   which is waiting for a delayed presention of  to complete error in connection_block_invoke_2:
>   Connection interrupted

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // OUTLETS *******************************************

    // Image
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // ACTIONS *******************************************    

    // Button
    @IBAction func pickImage(_ sender: Any) {

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        // set imagePickerController as delegate
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        // provide actionSheet to display the camera and photo  options
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Source", message: "Take a picture or select a photo", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        // add camera action to imagePickerController
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction) in

            // check if the camera is available
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            }
            else {
                print("Camera not available")
            }

        }))

        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // add photos action to imagePickerController
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photos", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction) in imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary}))

        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // cancel
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // assign image to imageView

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage

        imageView.image = image

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    // dismiss the image selector

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to present the `actionSheet` after presenting `imagePickerController` which is not possible. You need to present the `imagePickerController` in the `UIAlertAction`'s handler block. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func pickImage(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    // set imagePickerController as delegate
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    // provide actionSheet to display the camera and photo  options
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Source", message: "Take a picture or select a photo", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // add camera action to imagePickerController
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction) in

        // check if the camera is available
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
        }
        else {
            print("Camera not available")
        }

        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))


    // add photos action to imagePickerController
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photos", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))


    // cancel
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func pickImage(_ sender: Any) {

let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.delegate = self


let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Source", message: "Take a picture or select a photo", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)


actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction) in


    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
      self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }  else {
        print("Camera not available")
    }

}))




actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photos", style: .default, handler:{(action:UIAlertAction) in   

imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }))

// cancel
actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}